# How do I get profile image from facebook?

Tags: android, facebook, image, bitmap

I'm having problems downloading the profile picture . When I add this line to start the id:

```
userIds2 = profile.getId();
```

Class

```
public class MainFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

private Database databaseHelper;
private AccessTokenTracker mTokenTracker;
private ProfileTracker mProfileTracker;
private TextView mTextDetails;
private ImageView imageTeste;
private CallbackManager mCallbackManager;
private ImageView fbUserAvatar;
static String name;
static String idade;
private String userIds;
public String userIds2;
static byte[] image;
private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> mCallback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
        AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
        Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
        displayWelcomeMessage(profile);
        downloadAvatar();
        Intent it2 = new Intent(MainFragment.this.getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(it2);

    }
    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException e) {

    }
};
public MainFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    AccessTokenTracker tracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
        @Override
        protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken old, AccessToken newToken) {

        }
    };

    ProfileTracker profileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
        @Override
        protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile oldProfile, Profile newProfile) {
            //displayWelcomeMessage(newProfile);
        }
    };
    tracker.startTracking();
    profileTracker.startTracking();
}
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton)view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions("user_friends");
    loginButton.setFragment(this);
    loginButton.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, mCallback);
    imageTeste = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageTeste);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
}

public void displayWelcomeMessage(Profile profile){
    if (profile != null){

        name = profile.getName();
        idade = profile.getLastName();
    }
}

private synchronized void downloadAvatar() {
    Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
    userIds2 = profile.getId();
    AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap>() {
        @Override
        public Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
            URL fbAvatarUrl = null;
            try {
                fbAvatarUrl = new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/"+userIds2+"/picture?type=large");
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Bitmap fbAvatarBitmap = null;
            try {
                fbAvatarBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fbAvatarUrl.openConnection().getInputStream());

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return fbAvatarBitmap;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {//result vindo null, ver paginas que acessei ontem
            //imageTeste.setImageBitmap(result);

            image = convertBitmapToByteArray(result);

            databaseHelper = new Database(getActivity());

            boolean exist = databaseHelper.checkDataBase();
            if(exist == false) {

                Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
                name = profile.getName();
                idade = profile.getLastName();
            long id2 = databaseHelper.insertData(name, idade, image);
            if(id2 < 0){
                Message.message(getActivity(), "Unsuccessful");
            } else{
                Message.message(getActivity(), "Successfully Inserted a Row");
            }
            }
        }

    };
    task.execute();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
    displayWelcomeMessage(profile);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    //mTokenTracker.stopTracking();
    //mProfileTracker.stopTracking();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

public static byte[] convertBitmapToByteArray(Bitmap bitmap) {
    if (bitmap == null) {
        return null;
    } else {
        byte[] b = null;
        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, byteArrayOutputStream);
            b = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return b;
    }
}
```

}

Error logcat

```
enter code here
10-02 18:49:05.509    8338-8338/br.com.xxx E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: br.com.xxx, PID: 8338
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null,      request=129742, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {br.com.xxx/br.com.xxx.IntroActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3365)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3408)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1244)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at br.com.xxx.MainFragment.downloadAvatar(MainFragment.java:140)
    at br.com.xxx.MainFragment.access$000(MainFragment.java:46)
    at br.com.xxx.MainFragment$1.onSuccess(MainFragment.java:67)
    at br.com.xxx.MainFragment$1.onSuccess(MainFragment.java:60)
    at com.facebook.login.LoginManager.finishLogin(LoginManager.java:509)
    at com.facebook.login.LoginManager.onActivityResult(LoginManager.java:192)
    at com.facebook.login.LoginManager$1.onActivityResult(LoginManager.java:140)
    at com.facebook.internal.CallbackManagerImpl.onActivityResult(CallbackManagerImpl.java:82)
    at br.com.xxx.MainFragment.onActivityResult(MainFragment.java:210)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:165)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5423)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3361)
```

Answer (score 0):

For Uri of the profile picture try `getProfilePictureUri()` method to download profile picture.

Visit [Android - get facebook profile picture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19855072/android-get-facebook-profile-picture) or [how to download Facebook profile picture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14411990/how-to-download-facebook-profile-picture)